# HighCharts + reveal.js chart size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts, reveal.js

I present many chart in a reveal.js presentation but I met a problem, some of my chart randomly resize their size and I need to refresh the page to get it at the normal size again. this is the code

```
<section>
    <center>
        <div id="chart1" style="min-width: 465px; height: 600px; max-width: 900px;"></div>
    </center>
    </section>
<section>
<center>
        <div id="chart2" style="min-width: 465px; height: 600px; max-width: 900px;"></div>
</center>
```

I had to add `<center></center>` other way sometimes the chart was not display at the center of the slide and if I also refresh the page the chart was centered. I joined some screenshot. 
problem of the center:

[image: Chart not at the center]
[image: After Refresh]
But I don't have the problem if I put `<center></center>`

Probleme of the size:
[image: chart with a weird size]
[image: chart after refresh]

If you guys could help me finding a fix or if you got any idea what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<section>
    <center>
       <div id="chart1" style="height: 600px; width: 900px;"></div>
    </center>
</section>
```

That fix the problem.